# C# Error when I try to compile

Tags: c#

How do I go about resolving this issue? What other information can I look at?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
```

Additional information: `The type initializer for 'SpaceShip.Program' threw an exception.`

Comment: You should look at the full stack trace to see where in your code the exception is coming from.

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compiler error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation....

> When a class initializer fails to
>   initialize a type, a
>   TypeInitializationException is created
>   and passed a reference to the
>   exception thrown by the type's class
>   initializer. The InnerException
>   property of the
>   TypeInitializationException holds the
>   underlying exception.

So look at the inner exception to find out where the real problem is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242144%28VS.80%29.aspx

And I assume you know this, but JUST in case..  How to check the Inner Exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdwz4c0s%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look for errors that might occur in either SpaceShip.Program's static constructor, or in static variables that are initialized outside of any methods (e.g., private static Foo foo = new Foo();).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the error says: The Type Initialiser (aka the Constructor) threw an error.  Check the constructor of SpaceShip.Program.  Perhaps run it through the debugger.